# Is there any way to not re-installing packages each time on Google Colaborator?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I'm using Google Colaboratory with this [package](https://github.com/CliMT/climt):

I'm installing it using:

```
!pip3 install -v climt
```

But the problem is, that the installation takes almost 20 minutes - and I have to repeat it every ~hour.

Is there any way to keep the installation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that package always builds from source. I see on the [install page](http://climt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html):

> In the future, we plan to have binary distributions of CliMT.

I'd suggest opening an issue on the [GitHub project](https://github.com/CliMT/climt/issues) mentioning the use-case for binary wheels.